# A group action on a set

Tags: abstract-algebra

A group of order $15$ acts on a set of order $14$. Can there be no fixed points?

I know that orders of orbits have to divide the order of a group. So there are four possibilities: $1, 3, 5, 15$. We can exclude $15$ and $1$, so the question is: is there a solution in natural numbers for the equation $3n + 5m = 14$. And of course there is: $3\cdot3 + 1\cdot5 = 14$. Does it mean that the answer for the question is positive?

Comment: Well, there's always the *trivial* action, which fixes everything.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the actual question, yes there is such an action.

Let $G=Z_3\times Z_5$, and allow it to act on a set of order 3 by $(x,y)s=xs$ where $Z_3$ acts on the set of order 3 in the usual way. Similarly do the same for $Z_5$ on a five element set. Then take the disjoint union of 3 copies of the set of size three and 1 copy of the set of size five. Allow $G$ to act on an element by acting as it would on the element in the set of the disjoint union it comes from. Naturally the stabilizers of any element are as they were in the sets before taking the disjoint, and therefore none have order 15. Thus there are no fixed points.

Note that this is the subgroup of $S_{14}$ generated by the permutation $(1,2,3)(4,5,6)(7,8,9)(10,11,12,13,14)$.